# Blender points moving each other

Tags: blender

I am making a model of a boat in Blender. However, whenever I try to move just one point, all of the points near it are moving too. What setting do I need to change to fix this?
BTW, Whenever I click one point, a circle appears around where I clicked, and stays put, does this have anything to do with my problem?

I have tried

1. Selecting and deselecting all points
2. Restarting Blender
3. Comparing my sidebar to a project that doesn't act this way

None of these worked. As I am still relatively new to Blender I have no Idea what the any of the real functions are or how to change them so any answer needs to be simplified to near caveman level.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  I assume de-selecting all vertices and trying again.  It also might be helpful to have a screenshot of your top bar so we can see some things that are active.

Comment: you could try selecting all vertexes, deselecting, then just clicking on the single one you want.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I added more info, is this better?

Comment: @AMR that was the first thing I tried...

Comment: @Flotolk Have you already noticed http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions would be nice to have you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a icon, on the right side of the selection of vertex, edge, faces.. called [*Proportional editing*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit#Edit_mode). Press <kbd>O</kbd> to toggle it.

Make sure this is disabled.